# MySQL Query 3 tables linked by 2 linking tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database containing three tables: physician, office, specialty.
The physician table contains physician names. Likewise, the office table contains office addresses, and specialty contains the different specialties of the physicians in the practice.

Because physician and office are related many-to-many, I have a linking table, j_md_ofc. Likewise, I have a linking table j_md_spc for the many-to-many relationship between physicians and their specialties.

I am having difficulty creating a query that will list the physicians and their specialties that work at a specific office. The ultimate goal is to display on a web page for a given office the following:

1. Dr. Doe - joint replacement
2. Dr. Lumbergh - joint replacement, sports medicine
3. Dr. Soze - sports medicine, shoulder surgery, hand surgery
4. Dr. Swanson - sports medicine, shoulder surgery, joint replacement

Getting from the results of a query to the PHP needed to create the web page is no problem. Creating the query is where I'm stuck. Can it be done with a simple (?nested) query, or does it have to be 2 separate queries?

Comment: You should be able to do it with 4 `INNER JOIN` clauses in a single query. To get the specialties in a comma-separated list, use `GROUP_CONCAT`.

Comment: Four JOINs as @Barmar said. You can also use a LEFT or RIGHT JOIN for listing physicians that have no specialties.

Comment: There are many questions here about doing joins between tables with linking tables. A second linking table doesn't really change anything, you just repeat the same pattern.

Comment: `FROM table1 JOIN link_table_1_2 on ... JOIN table_2 ON ... JOIN link_table_2_3 ON ... JOIN table_3 ON ...`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmysql%5D+join+3+tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work (There should be faster ways though):

```
SELECT p.`name`, GROUP_CONCAT(s.name) from physician p
  /* Join physician and office */
  INNER JOIN j_md_ofc p2o
    ON (p.id = p2o.physician_id)
  /* Join speciality and physician */
  INNER JOIN j_md_spc p2s
    ON (p.id = p2s.physician_id)
  /* Join speciality_id with speciality name */
  INNER JOIN speciality s
    ON (s.id = p2s.speciality_id)
  /* Join office_id with office name */
  INNER JOIN office o
    ON (o.id = p2o.office_id)
WHERE o.name = "a"
GROUP BY p.name
```

Comment: Thank you. The commenting you included was extremely helpful. I was overthinking the problem and nesting joins within joins. For some reason, I just can't get my head around queries with many-to-many relationships. Thanks again.

Comment: @AnthonyWatson For me it helps to think about it in a non explicit join way like: select a.x, b.y, c.z from a, b, c WHERE a.id=b.some_id AND c.id = b.some_other_id

Comment: @SleepProgger thats actually a great way to understand these kind of things great tip. I always struggle with relational databases

Answer (score 0):

```
select physician_name, specialty_name, ...
from
    physicians p
    inner join physician_offices po
        on po.physician_id = p.physician_id
    inner join physician_specialities ps
        on ps.physician_id = p.physician_id
    inner join specialities s
        on s.specialty_id = ps.specialty_id
where
    po.office_id = ?
```

or maybe a better guess at table/column names:

```
select md.name, spc.name, ...
from
    md
    inner join j_md_ofc mo
        on mo.md_id = md.md_id
    inner join j_md_spc ms
        on ms.md_id = md.md_id
    inner join spc
        on spc.spc_id = ms.spc_id
where
    mo.ofc_id = ?
```